# Troubles connecting Bluetooth headset

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, bluetooth, headset

I've installed drivers and paired a headset, and everything works fine at this moment, I can make a call via Skype, etc. However when headset is turned off and than on again, everything stops working. Bluetooth audio devices in sound settings are shown as disconnected; if I manually run "Connect" menu they are shown as "Ready" after some time, but still no sound.
What can I do?